# How can I uninstall Foxit Reader from 16.04?

Tags: 16.04, uninstall, foxitreader

I installed it using the .deb package from their website and I've turned the internet upside down looking for a way to do so and nothing works, terminal doesn't recognize 'foxitreader' and when I use dpkg to list all the programs, it is just not listed, or listed below another name. HELP!

Comment: Let me clarify that using Ubuntu Software to remove it is... well, useless.

Comment: How did you install it?

Comment: What is the output of `dpkg --get-selections *foxit*`?

Comment: If i remember  correctly,  you install  foxit reader from deb package.  So removal would  be via `dpkg --remove` . You will need to know package name for that.  Use `dpkg --get-selections | grep foxit ` for that

Comment: @SujeetSinha says that no such package's been found

Comment: @Serg Sorry the terminal does nothing with that command, no message, nothing. Should I do something next or...?

Comment: @MarkKirby I installed downloading a .deb package from their website

Comment: @EliecerThoms what was the name of the deb file?

Comment: Eh,  somebody will probably  figure this out.  If not,  I'll  install foxit and just write and answer that goes through  the steps of removing once i wake up. It's  a bit late where i am.

Comment: @SujeetSinha FoxitReader2.1.0805_Server_x64_enu_Setup.run

Comment: I don't get a .deb from there, it is a .run https://www.foxitsoftware.com/products/pdf-reader/ Youi need to run that again and choose uninstall.

Comment: @MarkKirby whoa, nice. will do.

Comment: Although I'm not sure, but can you try `dpkg --get-selections *Foxit*`?

Comment: @MarkKirby helped me figure it out, uninstalled.  Thank you all.

Comment: @MarkKirby just post it

Comment: Uninstall does not remove Foxit file associations.  And for some reason Foxit tries to open everything (even though it is uninstalled).

Answer (score 77):

The installer tells you where the file was installed in. For me it was `~/opt/foxitsoftware/foxitreader`. In that directory is "maintenancetool.sh", running it will give you a gui for uninstalling.

Comment: Can you add some detail here? What folder was it installed in?

Comment: Done @MarkKirby

Comment: Wait, `home/user/opt` ? Should that not be just `/opt`?

Comment: That's what it showed.

Comment: I guess the installer made that directory then.

Comment: Works on 20.04 as well.

Answer (score 29):

The foxit reader program is installed manually. To uninstall, go to `~/opt/foxitsoftware/foxitreader` and then run `./maintenancetool` file and click uninstall.

Comment: Right solution for Ubuntu 18.04, tested!

Comment: Tested in Ubuntu 20.04, OK.

Answer (score 7):

I was facing the same issue while uninstalling Foxit reader in my ubuntu 16.04.
Then I did the following steps,

```
cd ~/opt/foxitsoftware/foxitreader/
sudo ./maintenancetool.sh
```

if I write ./maintanacetool.sh and try to uninstall, it was giving permission error so with sudo it worked fine.

Answer (score 5):

I tried every method I saw, but none did the job. The `./maintenancetool` didn't do the trick. Also the `./uninstaller` was worthless.

So I used:

```
rm -R /opt/foxitsoftware
```

I'm not sure whether this could have negative consequences though.

Answer (score 2):

1. Goto foxit installed directory and open uninstall.desktop in that directory using a texteditor
2. see the exec=
   Example(for me):-
   exec = /home/hiren/opt/foxitsoftware/foxitreader/maintenancetool.sh %F
3. Run the exec ="This " in the terminal
   Example(for me):-
     sudo /home/hiren/opt/foxitsoftware/foxitreader/maintenancetool.sh %F

Ubuntu version - 19.10

Answer (score 1):

The download is not for a .deb file, it is a .run file.

The .run file is not installed via `dpkg`, it is a custom installer.

The way to remove it is, run the .run file again and find the directory where it was installed.

In this folder you will find an `uninstall` file, run this to remove Foxit.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I uninstalled it:

Copy this > `./maintenancetool`

Go to /home/opt/foxitsoftware

Right click at some empty space and "open in terminal"

Paste `./maintenancetool` and click Enter. It will open a GUI which will help you remove the folder which you would've removed by simply selecting 'opt' folder and clicking the delete button.