# How to uninstall foxit reader from Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: command-line, 20.04, pdf, foxitreader

I'm trying in every possible way to delete this PDF reader, but I'm not getting it. A while ago, I "uninstalled" deleting the files from the computer.

downloaded file: https://www.linuxcapable.com/en/how-to-install-foxit-pdf-reader-on-ubuntu-20-04/
filename: FoxitReader.enu.setup.2.4.4.0911.x64.run.tar.gz.1

Steps:

```
wget http://cdn01.foxitsoftware.com/pub/foxit/reader/desktop/linux/2.x/2.4/en_us/FoxitReader.enu.setup.2.4.4.0911.x64.run.tar.gz

cd ~/Downloads

tar xzvf FoxitReader*.tar.gz

sudo chmod a+x FoxitReader*.run

sudo chmod a+x FoxitReader*.run
```

Comment: Details are unclear. How did you install this software to begin with? What files did you delete?  Details are also incomplete. If you've tried "every possible way", please include these details so that we can understand the current state of your system.

Comment: @Nmath done. I hope I made it clear. Thanks for your tips.

Comment: Hmmm... Well since you didn't install this software with your package manager, you can't remove it that way. I looked through your link and also skimmed through the documentation from foxit.com and I don't see any instructions to uninstall this software. One of the burdens and risks of manually installing software is that you're responsible for manually removing it. To add complexity, the installation you ran is *proprietary software* that we don't know how it works or what it actually did to your computer. I suggest that you contact the developers of this application for removal instructions.

Comment: Thanks Man, i appreciate.

Comment: I even triead this https://askubuntu.com/questions/1329621/how-to-uninstall-foxit-reader-from-ubuntu-20-04-using-terminal but i cant even find the directory.

Comment: [This answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1329629) - best explains why you can't uninstall the software. My suggestion is to contact the developers of the software. In the future, to avoid these kinds of problems, don't install untrusted proprietary software that has no documentation that explains what the installer does and no instructions for how to remove it. There are plenty of applications in Ubuntu repositories that can read PDF files. The PDF format has been open since 2008- paid or proprietary software is not necessary.

Comment: If you already manually deleted files for the software, then removing the `.desktop` file will remove the application shortcut. But again, since we have no idea what that installer really did, who knows what could still be left behind.  Also, if you manually removed files, then an uninstall script probably won't work anymore, even if the developers had provided one.

Comment: here I found a similar question. Try the solutions, if you have not already.
https://askubuntu.com/questions/816678/how-can-i-uninstall-foxit-reader-from-16-04

Answer (score 4):

To uninstall, go to `cd ~/opt/foxitsoftware/foxitreader` and then run `./maintenancetool` file and click uninstall.

I hope that helps. <3